# how to use fonts.conf to select specific font

Tags: highcharts, fonts

fonts.conf newbie!

I have a font family containing 19 different styles. These range from the usual Bold, Italic, Bold Italic etc to Condensed Light, Condensed Light Italic, Thin Italic, Black, ...

I have an app (highcharts) that uses JSON that can contain fontFamily and, optionally, fontStyle. The app appears to be accessing the fonts.conf.

My question is: what should the fonts.conf look like that will take something like:

```
fontFamily: "CModernCondLtIt"
```

and select the physical font file: CModern-CondLight-Italic.ttf

Assuming that the output of fc-list -v shows:
...  family: "Ch Modern"(s)
style: "Condensed Light Italic"(s) "Cond Light Italic"(s)
fullname: "Ch Modern Cond Light Italic"(s)
file: "/usr/share/fonts/CModern-CondLight-Italic.ttf"(s)

Would I use match or alias?
and what would the XML look like?

Comment: I am afraid that from the Highcharts perspective nothing could be done here... Just like you wrote - Highcharts expects to have the font family defined in this way: `fontFamily: "CModernCondLtIt"`

Comment: What is the algorithm for how HighCharts looks up and/or replaces the font?  Is this documented somewhere.

Comment: Sebastian Wędzel - I've edited fonts so that the family is "Ch Modern Cond Bold" with its style or weight set to regular.

Installed the fonts, ran fc-cache and fc-list -s "Ch Modern Cond Bold" and it returns "CModern-CondBold.ttf: "Ch Modern Cond Bold" "Condensed" - which is the correct font file.    Why does highcharts refuse to select this font?   Instead I get "BirchStd" in the PDF???????   This is beyond annoying. Quite frankly its unusable.

Comment: To be honest - I don't know how to help you. Are you sure that you added the font from the fonts.conf properly? Adding custom font-sizes to Highcharts it's easy, all you need is import this font family and assign it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/90r6bhgx/